# CollectionViewController Header start from screen edge Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, header, collectionview

I have a collectionviewcontroller and have added a header view to it in code. The header is starting from under the status bar so it looks weird because my header is colored while my collection view is white.

Is there any way to fix this, or at least get the color. I tried using a view but it then appears over the header, and if i change the z position it then goes behind the whole collectionview.

I have tried constrainting like so

```
self.collectionView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: self.view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
```

When I run, the status bar area just goes black and the header stays at the same spot 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its due to collection view's `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` property.
Just set it to `never` like blow:

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
 let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

        let myCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers. Edit the one answer to include any differences. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set inset like this:

```
collectionView.contentInset.top = 44
```

Or **at least you can get and set color** like this:
you can make an UICollectionViewController to handle the UICollectionView and in Interface Builder activate the Footer section, 
[image]

then you can use the following method:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                             at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath)

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return headerView

    default:

        assert(false, "kind unsupported")
    }
}
```